# Is bluetooth a standard or a technology?

Tags: bluetooth

typical definitions say "bluetooth is a standard"
but, at times bluetooth is referred  to as "bluetooth technology"

Answer (score 7):

> Bluetooth is an open wireless **technology standard** for exchanging data over short distances (using short wavelength radio transmissions) from fixed and mobile devices, creating personal area networks (PANs) with high levels of security.

So... both?

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth)

Answer (score 2):

It's both actually. It's a technology, as it does things a certain way, and it grew to be the standard (according to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/standard),  "something considered by an authority or by general consent as a basis of comparison; an approved model.") way of transmitting data over short distances.